# How to create different resolution images in air with respect to Aspect Ratio Using Gd Library and PHP

Tags: php, image, file, upload, gd

I m Creating a Wallpaper Website, and i need images automatically converts to different resolutions with respect to there aspect ratio as user uploads.. As seen in most wallpaper Websites... 1920x1080 , 1360x1200 like these

Comment: Are you sure none of the 65376593 examples for that on google answer your question?

Comment: i m new to php, well i tried a lot,

Comment: Then show what you tried and explain what did not work. _Then_ we can help. Otherwise your question read like: "please do my work for me". So post your code please. Thanks!